# PostgreSQL why can table aliases be referenced inside subquery WHERE but not FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm wondering why a reference to a table alias in the `FROM` clause is invalid, but it is valid to reference a column using the alias in the `WHERE` clause within the same subquery.

Here are two example queries: the first produces the error `relation "t1" does not exist`, but the second is valid:

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM existing_table WHERE conditioncol < 1000) AS t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.conditioncol < existing_table.conditioncol + 50)


SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM existing_table WHERE conditioncol < 1000) AS t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM existing_table WHERE t1.conditioncol < existing_table.conditioncol + 50)
```

Note that the only difference in these two queries is that the first has `FROM t1` whereas the second has `FROM existing_table` in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing table aliases with qualified column names.

What you are referencing in a correlation clause is a *column* name.  The table alias is differentiating where the column comes from.

If you want to reference the same subquery in more than one place, then use a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select . . .
     )
select . . .
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where . . . );
```

Comment: I'm in the process of going from CTEs to trying to use subqueries instead because of the fact that CTEs are optimization fences in postgres.  Also, would you mind elaborating on why referencing a table alias is not valid but referencing a column using that alias is?

Comment: @user3747260 . . . I thought I explained that.  *outer* column references are supported, but not *outer* table-only references.

Comment: Yes, but my question is _why_ this is the case.  It seems like a very intentional design decision to allow one but not the other.

Comment: @user3747260 . . . It is a very intentional design decision.  There is a simple way to include the same "table" reference in the query (use a CTE).  There is not a way to include an outer column reference.